# Read in file to single array and then check if a number is in that array

Tags: arrays, file, matlab, parsing, set

I've got a .txt file set up in the following format:

```
7
8
9
10
```

What I'm trying to do, is read in the numbers from the file into an array and then check if a number I'm getting from a different function is contained within that array.

```
ismember(ruleFunc{x+1},memFunc}
```

I'm pretty sure that will check if the element from ruleFunc is in the array memFunc and return 1/0 if it is or isn't. But I can't get the ismember function to work properly because the method I'm using to populate the memFunc array is wrong.

Additionally, how am I able to add another number to the .txt file on a new line?

**EDIT:**

Here is how I am populating memFunc currently. It's also the same method that populates ruleFunc.

```
mem=fopen('WorkingMemory.txt');
    tline = fgets(mem); 
    workMem = {}; 
    index = 1; 
while ischar(tline)   
    workMem{index} = str2num(tline); 
    tline = fgets(mem); 
    index = index + 1; 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `ismember` returns a matrix that is 1 where the inputs are equal. (See the documenation for more information.) You might actually want something that returns a number, 1 or 0, depending on weather or not your number is in the matrix at all. I've included both options below.

```
% read in file
filename = 'my_data.txt';
fid  = fopen(filename);
data = textscan(fid, '%d');
data = data{1};
fclose(fid);

% determine if number is in the file
number = 33;
ismember(data,number) %this returns an array
length(find(data == number)) > 0 % this returns 1 or 0

%write a line to existing file
fid2 = fopen(filename,'a');
newnumber = 100;
fprintf(fid2, '%d\n', newnumber);
fclose(fid2);
```

Now I see your updated answer. That code will read each line into a different cell of a cell array. You want all your data in a matrix.  You could rearrange your cell array and put the data into a matrix or you could use `textscan` as described above.

In response to your comment, you can make an if statement like this:

```
if (length(find(data == number)) > 0) 
    'do something'
end
```

Comment: How can I fit that middle part into an if statement?

Comment: Also, if I take the fclose line out of the top portion, will I be able use the bottom portion without doing the fopen?

Comment: I've added an if statement to my answer.  No, you cannot take out the fclose.  The first fopen opens the file for reading (by default) and the second opens it for appending.

Comment: Okay. So the ismember line isn't necessary for the length line to work?

Comment: Nope. I was just giving you options.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for the help, I've got it pretty much working at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are actually creating an array containing strings instead of numbers?

If it's not as simple as that, more information / code snippets would be useful. You mention the method populating **memFunc** may be wrong, maybe you could post that code?

Comment: Note: I would have added this as a comment to the question, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Updated the original post to include the code. The workMem array is created in main and passed to the function as memFunc